# Standard way to attach unit tests to a C# project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I've written couple of unit tests in seperate project. While developing, I loaded the dll into NUnit.exe each time to check the results. Given that I am done with writing unit tests, how to organize and attach unit tests to the solution.

I'd tried creating "tools" folder in the solution directory and then placed all NUnit related libraries and in postbuild event of the test project I hooked up the nunit like below and it works.

```
"$(SolutionDir)tools\nunit\nunit-console.exe" "$(TargetPath)"
```

But in one of my tests, I refer to a sqlite DB. If I hardcode its location it works fine but I intend to place it in the tests project under "App_Data" folder. So, I tried with below code to get relative path but it is not working. But when I copied the file to "tools" folder it is working fine, I'd guess execution context is from NUnit folder.

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),"App_Data\\test.txt")
```

Comment: Why does your __unit test__ read a physical text file?

Comment: Sorry its a sqlite db file for unit tests.

Comment: The same question applies:  Why does your **unit test** read from an actual database?

Comment: It is a sqlite database, actual database is SQL Server. Sqlite database contains data required for just unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need specifically nunit, you could as well use built-in visual studio support for unit testing... It has been incorporated to the newest Express editions as well and you don't have to struggle with problems like this ;)

Either way, I believe you've misunderstood the basics of unit testing. We never test against an actual database, that's a very bad practice. You should do some research on the topic and see the theory behind `mocking` stuff like this.

Comment: It is sqlite database that is used for just unit tests. Application's actual database is SQL Server.

Comment: @Sundeep, that still doesn't really advocate its use. What if you decide to use a completely different way of storing things in the future? Your unit tests can't be dependent on a thing like this... Well, they can, but it's not a good idea. Do what you want, I just felt it's a good idea to point this out as well. If not for you, maybe for someone else who'd care.

Comment: I hear what you said, in my case the design is restricting to inject mock values since they are tightly coupled with DB layer. So, we preferred this way, it is same as in-memory objects but data is extracted from simple select statements which eventually map into DTO.